# Get key with largest value from a dictionary in Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am using a Dictionary where the keys are strings and the values are integers. How can I get the key with the largest value out of this Dictionary?

I know there is the `associationsDo:` method I can use to iterate over both keys and values, but I don't know how to get the maximum value.

```
| countDict |
countDict := Dictionary new.
...
countDict associationsDo: [ :k :v | ??? ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to do it following your idea:

```
| max largest |
max := nil.
countDict associationsDo: [:k :v |
  (max isNil or: [v > largest])
    ifTrue: [
      max := k.
      largest := v]].
^max
```

---

Here is another way, shorter but not very efficient:

```
 countDict isEmpty ifTrue: [^nil].
 ^countDict keyAtValue: countDict max
```

---

Also, if you have a `countDict` I suspect that it represents the number of occurrences of every key. If that is the case you shouldn't be using a `Dictionary` but a `Bag`. Instances of `Bag` represent collections of objects which may have several occurrences each. Examples:

```
names := Bag new.
people do: [:person | names add: person firstName].
```

and you may end up with

```
2 occurrences of 'John'
1 occurrence of 'Paul'
4 occurrences of 'Ringo'
7 occurrences of 'George'

names occurrencesOf: 'John'  ---->  2
```

The `Bag` will internally have a `countDict` sort of `Dictionary`, but to your model a `Bag` could reveal better your intention than a `Dictionary` because you will only need to `add:` elements without having to count them; the `Bag` will do it for you.

With a `Bag` your computation becomes

```
bag occurrencesOf: bag asSet max
```

The reason to send `asSet` is to avoid iterating several times on every value, which would happen if we simply put `bag max`. This simpler code will also work, but given that `max` iterates using `do:` and `Bag` implements `do:` by repeating the evaluation of the block for every occurrence of the element, this solution would be less efficient.

A better approach would be to re-implement `max` (and `min`) in `Bag` so that each element is iterated once. This would be similar to the code that we have above which followed your initial idea (`associationsDo: [`...). But let's  leave the details of this as an exercise for the reader.

Anyway, if we re-implemnted `max` in `Bag`, the code would become simple and efficient at once:

```
 bag occurrencesOf: bag max
```

Comment: I think you are getting the key with the largest key size from the dictionary. I am looking for the key with the largest associated value. So shouldn't it be `(max isNil or: [v > size])` and assign `size := v`? Also, while this is a nice solution, I was hoping for some build-in `maximum` function that could do this, but maybe there is not.

Comment: You are right. I had misunderstood you. I've changed the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another nice way to do this:

```
(countDict associations detectMax: #value) key
```

Comment: The one-liner I have been looking for, great!